# How number of hadoop partition decide

Tags: hadoop

I have one question regarding the partition in map reduce. How the developer/user decide how many partition should be created to process the input files. Is there any standard way to decide ? The number of reducer will always be same as the number of partitions? What is the In Memory merge in Map reduce? How I will get the complete picture step by step of the Map reduce.

Thanks

Comment: The answer to this question is very broad, I would recommend you read MapReduce chapter from Hadoop Definitive Guide to learn exactly how MapReduce works internally.

Comment: I read it,but I did not get what is the parameter to decide the number of Partition.

Comment: The number of petitions is equal to number of reducers.

Comment: Yes , That I understand,but what is the parameter to decide the number of partition.

Comment: Those are actullay 4 different questions. I suggest posting them / looking them up individually, or removing any of those that you have already found an answer for.

Comment: Now my question is what is the parameter to decide the number of partition